# Mysql date query to find if the current is within two dates?

Tags: mysql, date

In my table I have two fields: start_date and end_date.  I'm just trying to retrieve rows where the current date is between the start and end dates.  For some reason, I am *not* getting this at all.  I've tried using between, but I keep getting empty sets even though I know that there are records that exist...  I don't think I'm thinking about this clearly... Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Could you please post some records that should be returned but they are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   SYSDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Make sure your `start_date` and `end_date` are `DATE` or `DATETIME`, not `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it without using BETWEEN:

```
WHERE @date >= start_date AND @date <= end_date
```

It should be equivalent though.

Also note that often what you *really* want is a half-open interval:

```
WHERE @date >= start_date AND @date < end_date
```

If you are paging, using a half-open interval avoids repeating values at the end of one page at the start of the next. You can't express this with the BETWEEN syntax.